# Shiny run client-side (in browser)

Tags: r, shiny, browser

The Shiny package DT has the possibility to run both server side (by default) and client-side:

DT::renderDataTable(iris, server = FALSE)

I would like to run my whole app client-side. So the user connects to data that doesn't arrive on my server, but remains in the browser-session of the client. I thought I had seen this as possibility, but now I'm trying to find it, I'm not so sure.

Is it possible to do this?

EDIT: The question was intended for running shiny in browser, without installing anything else on the side of the user.

Comment: "whole app" ... do you mean running R in the browser or on the client machine?

Comment: yeah I was thinking R in the browser. On the client machine would be more something like Docker I guess?

Comment: I suggest what you're asking for is rather evolutionary: R is not a trivial language, and expecting that (1) the client has R available in a docker image, (2) web-browser/javascript can somehow communicate with said docker image, and (3) shiny can be adapted to handle that ... are all rather big. There _is_ a project for running R in WebAssembly (https://github.com/r-wasm/webr), though again, that's unlikely to be a fast fix, I'm not even sure of its completeness or extensibility with other packages.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve where running R in the browser context seems like the right idea?

Comment: Like I said: I thought I had seen somewhere that it was possible to run Shiny in the browser. Thinking about it, I realise that is quite a strech. The docker thing is an entirely different solution of course.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve: Provide a R shiny dashboard for users, without having their data. I know what the data looks like, I have all the buttons, but how to ensure the data doesn't enter 'my' server.

Comment: Ahhh, that's an interesting problem! Unfortunately until R/shiny runs perfectly natively in the browser, I think the best you could do would be to upload to a temp-file that would be deleted on process-exit. This likely doesn't meet your ideal "clean" intent, I can't think of a way to do that with R/shiny.

Comment: The python version of shiny can run without a web server https://shiny.rstudio.com/py/docs/shinylive.html but the R version cannot yet because there is no WASM assembler for R yet. I do believe folks are working on it.

Comment: Thank you both! I must have mixed up R Shiny and Python Shiny. Let's hoop WASM/R work continues smoothly. For this project I will look in a different direction.